# Can a procedure, contained in a module, call another procedure contained in the same module?

Tags: fortran, procedure, gfortran, fortran90, procedural-programming

Consider a module that generates the first few primes:

```
module module_primes
 
contains

function is_prime(n)
    ! Function to check if a number is prime. 
    
    implicit none
    integer :: n, m
    logical :: is_prime
    
    is_prime = .true.
    
    do m=2, n-1
        
        if ( mod(n,m) == 0 ) then
            is_prime = .false. 
        end if
        
    end do

end function is_prime


subroutine prime_gen( list )
    ! Subroutine that takes an array, say of size L, and puts first L primes in it. 

    implicit none
    integer, dimension(:) :: list 
    integer ::  n, counter = 0
    logical :: is_prime
    
    do n=3, huge(1)-1
        
        if ( is_prime(n)  ) then
            counter = counter + 1
            list(counter) = n
        end if
        
        if (counter == size( list) ) then
            exit
        end if
        
    end do

end subroutine prime_gen

end module module_primes
```

I am aware that doing something similar inside a `program` is incorrect (internal procedures can not reference each other). Inside a module as with the code above, the exact error message is (Mac OS terminal with GFortran compiler)

```
% gfortran module_primes.o main_primes.o -o primes.exe

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_is_prime_", referenced from:
      ___module_primes_MOD_prime_gen in module_primes.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Presently I am putting `is_prime` outside the module (I guess that's what is referred to as 'external procedures') as follows

```
module module_primes
 
contains

subroutine prime_gen( list )
...    
        if ( is_prime(n)  ) then
...
end subroutine prime_gen

end module module_primes


function is_prime(n)
...
end function is_prime
```

And it works as intended. The reason I am not satisfied with that is I want `is_prime` to be available to programs that `use module_primes`; now it is available only to the procedures that are defined inside this module file.

Is the cause of the error what I mentioned, or something else?

Comment: Remove the `logical :: is_prime` declaration from the subroutine `prime_gen`.

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Comment: [original post on Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/38953/20688)

Comment: When you use "sin(1.0)" you do not define "REAL::sin()" because is a function. That is why the must delete the line "logical :: is_prime", as @francescalus said in his comment, because you are using a function.

Comment: @user1063306 yeah makes sense.